# how do i check button with unique index jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, unique

[image]
Expected Output: if `isbulk` is true display `Send button` and if `isbulk` is false `Send button` is hide

I am facing an issue in javascript. I want to find `send button` unique index, enable and disable `send button` a/c to unique index.

how i can do this?

my code logic:
i try it but not working

```js
function showTemplate(index, template) {
console.log(template); // {name: "test1", body: "test1", isbulk: true}
                       // {name: "test2", body: "test2", isbulk: false}
console.log(index); // 0
                    // 1

if(templates[index].isbulk === true){    //find send button unique index
$(`.send_button`).prop('disabled', false);  // Enable
} 
else if(templates[index].isbulk === false){
$(`.send_button`).prop('disabled', true); // Disable
$('.send_button').hide();   
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- send button -->
<td>
<button class="send_button btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
</td>
```

What should i do? Anyone help me?

Comment: Add more html code...Also , how does `showTemplate` gets called ?

Answer (score 0):

***I hope*** below is your required code. I am assuming an array of object for `template`. `showTemplate()` function will work to enable/disable `send` button according to the `bulk` flag

```js
function showTemplate(template) {
  for (var index = 0; index < template.length; index++) {
    console.log(template);
    console.log(template[index]);

    if (template[index].isbulk === true) {
      $(`.send_button`).prop('disabled', false);
    } else if (template[index].isbulk === false) {
      $(`.send_button`).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
}

showTemplate([{
  name: "test1",
  body: "test1",
  isbulk: true
}, {
  name: "test2",
  body: "test2",
  isbulk: false
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <button class="send_button btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
</td>
```

Comment: thanks i try bro but it not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6390817/solanki)